# datePick only shows when double clicking

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to implement a date pick on my website, but I got a little problem:
to make it appear, I have to click on the text field, click outside and then click inside again to show up.
How do I fix that? Heres part of my code:

```
                 function datePicker(){                         
                $( "#from" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );
                    }
                });
                $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );
                    }
                });
            }   
    <input type="text" class ="date" id= "from" name="from" onclick="datePicker();"/>
    <BR>
    <input type="text" class = "date" id= "to" name="to" onfocus="datePicker();"/>
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following: in the function `datePicker()` you instantiate the datepicker, and only after that it will know to open it.

Remove the function line and the onclick="" to look like this:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $( "#from" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );
                    }
                });
                $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );
                    }
                });
            });  
       </script>
    <input type="text" class ="date" id= "from" name="from" />
    <BR>
    <input type="text" class = "date" id= "to" name="to"/>
```

Comment: My bad, place the javascript code between `<script>` tags, I modified the code to work now

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     datePicker();
});
```

Call datePicker function on document.ready and remove onclick then try

Comment: That didnt do anything at all ):